# SQL Recursion CTE infinite loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have this example which i cannot understand and i hope you could help me with it!

I have a train lines table which looks like this:

[image]

The task is to get every possible destination from a given Start (recursively).

I've tried to do it like this:

```sql
    with cte (st, nd) as(
    select from1, to1
    from RailwayTbl
    where from1 = 'Berlin'

    union all

    select e.from1, e.to1
    from RailwayTbl e join cte
    on cte.nd = e.from1
    )
    select * from cte;
```

When executed, i got the following error:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion. ((It is an infinite loop..))

And when i removed the `all` and used `union` only i got this error:

> Recursive common table expression 'cte' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you actually using? That looks like  SQL Server error, not MySQL.

Comment: Your data is an image, rather than `text`, so we can't test, but that looks like you have a multiple circular references. For example `'Amsterdam'` -> `'Berlin'` -> `'Amsterdam'` -> `'Berlin'` -> `'Amsterdam'` ....  -> `'Berlin'` -> `'Amsterdam'` ... -> `'Berlin'` -> `'Amsterdam'`... you get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the recursion, which is a pain in SQL Server.  The following keeps a string of the visited stations to stop the recursion:

```
 with cte as (
       select from1 as st, to1 as nd, concat(',', st, ',', to1) as dests, 1 as lev
       from RailwayTbl
       where from1 = 'Berlin'
       union all
       select e.from1, e.to1, concat(cte.dests, e.to1, ',') as dests, lev + 1
       from RailwayTbl e join
            cte
            on cte.nd = e.from1
       where dests not like concat('%,', e.nd, ',%')
    )
select * from cte;
```

I also added `lev`.  Often I use `where lev < 10` on the recursive part of the cte definition for debugging.